# Display Results from query in a select tag in wordpress page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have a WordPress page that connects to an external database from WordPress using the following code:

```
$my_wpdb = new wpdb('me', 'password', 'database', 'localhost');

$myrows = $my_wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Name FROM testing" );
```

...then i use `print_r($myrows);` and get the following:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Name] => Jesus
         )

  [1] => stdClass Object (
            [Name] => James
         )

  [2] => stdClass Object (
            [Name] => Matt
         )
)
```

Now I need to output the names inside those objects in a select tag using php.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that each `Name` in each row should be an `<option>` in a `<select>` html tag?

Comment: @dewd yes so up there it says jesus,james,matt i need it to show up as options the code below dose nto work since im using shortcodes[insertphp][/insertphp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($myrows as $myrow) : ?>
    <option value=""><?php echo $myrow->Name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Also, by the looks of your table it might be easier to just use WordPress [`get_col()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column) function, which works pretty much the same way as `get_results` but should directly return "Name".

---

**EDIT** - Maybe the [insertphp] plugin likes this version better:

```
<select>
[insertphp]
foreach ($myrows as $myrow) {
    echo '<option>' . $myrow->Name . '</option>';
}
[/insertphp]
</select>
```

Also, please provide any error info that might help troubleshoot the problem otherwise.

Comment: i should of mentioned this before im using [insertphp][/insertphp] short code i took out the <?php ?> and the code dose not see to work

Comment: i am not familiar with the [insertphp] plugin... if it's an issue with the plugin, maybe try changing the `:` for `{` and the `endforeach` for a `{`, though I don't think that's the problem.
Is there any way you can test this in raw php?

Comment: @jamespotter1 see my edit above, maybe that will help with the plugin